# Proper Mutex Lock Placement for Singleton Instance in Multithreaded C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, singleton

I'm implementing a thread-safe Singleton pattern in C++ based on an example from the **"Head First Design Patterns"** book, which originally presents the pattern in Java. I'm aware that since C++11, the initialization of static local variables is thread-safe.
However, I'm uncertain about the placement of the mutex lock in relation to the `getInstance()` call in my static class methods. Should the `mutex` be locked before or after the `getInstance()` call? Here's the relevant code snippet:
I think it should be after because `ChocolateBoilerSingleton::getInstance();` is thread-safe. But I'd like to know other opinions here.

Thank you.

```
#include <mutex>
class ChocolateBoilerSingleton
{

public:

    ChocolateBoilerSingleton(const ChocolateBoilerSingleton&) = delete;
    ChocolateBoilerSingleton& operator=(const ChocolateBoilerSingleton&) = delete;

    static void fill()
    {
        auto& instance = ChocolateBoilerSingleton::getInstance();
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(instance.m_mtx);
        if (instance.isEmpty())
        {
            instance.m_empty = false;
            instance.m_boiled = false;
        }
    }

    static void boil()
    {
        auto& instance = ChocolateBoilerSingleton::getInstance();
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(instance.m_mtx);
        if (!instance.isEmpty() && !instance.isBoiled())
        {
            instance.m_boiled = true;
        }
    }

    static void drain()
    {
        auto& instance = ChocolateBoilerSingleton::getInstance();
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(instance.m_mtx);
        if (!instance.isEmpty() && instance.isBoiled())
        {
            instance.m_empty = true;
        }
    }

public:
    static ChocolateBoilerSingleton& getInstance()
    {
        static ChocolateBoilerSingleton instance;
        return instance;
    }
    bool isBoiled() const
    {
        return this->m_boiled;
    }

    bool isEmpty() const
    {
        return this->m_empty;
    }

    // Data --------------------
private:

    ChocolateBoilerSingleton() :
        m_mtx(),
        m_empty(true),
        m_boiled(false)
    {}
    std::mutex m_mtx;
    bool m_empty;
    bool m_boiled;

};

 int main()
{
    ChocolateBoilerSingleton::fill();
    ChocolateBoilerSingleton::boil();
    ChocolateBoilerSingleton::drain();
}
```

Comment: If you lock the mutex before retrieving the singleton then you could avoid the static local which may give you **marginally** better performance

Comment: What is the _purpose_ of the mutex? That is to say, what _guarantees_ do you want to provide when your singleton is concurrently used by two or more threads? Your example program only ever has a single thread, but what if there were three threads instead? What if `fill()`, `boil()`, and `drain()` were concurrently called by three different threads? What possible outcomes should be allowed in that case? What outcomes should be forbidden? There's no way to know whether you are using the mutex "correctly" if you can't say what guarantees the mutex is supposed to provide.

Answer (score 0):

`fill()`, `boil()` and `drain()` need not be static. Callers should use `getInstance()` method to get a reference to the singleton object, and invoke those member functions with the reference.

```
void fill() {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);
  if (isEmpty()) {
    m_empty = false;
    m_boiled = false;
  }
}
```

Same thing applies to `boil()` and `drain()`, and your `main()` function will be like this.

```
int main() {
  auto& boiler = ChocolateBoilerSingleton::getInstance();
  boiler.fill();
  boiler.boil();
  boiler.drain();

  return 0;
}
```

There's one more thing that should be mentioned.
**Lock your const getter methods.** It can be weired since you're accessing `m_boiled` and `m_empty` with read-only, but **any data that could be written by another thread should be locked** even though you're reading it. In your case, `fill()` and `boil()` can update the variable while you're trying read.

```
bool isBoiled() const {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);
  return this->m_boiled;
}
```

Don't forget to mark `m_mtx` as `mutable` since a const member can not lock mutex.

```
mutable std::mutex m_mtx;
```

In addition, you can consider using `std::atomic<bool>` which can get rid of `mutex`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I prefer my approach because I don't want to expose the internal parts of my classes by making ChocolateBoilerSingleton::getInstance() accessible to the outside world. I appreciate the feedback about locking the getter methods.

Comment: Also I think we might need to have std::recursive_mutex  because when fill() locks mutex , it needs to lock mutex again when isEmpty gets invoked.

Comment: @Sami, If you don't want to make `getInstance` public, then don't call the class a "singleton." A singleton is an _object,_ it's not a class. Your code creates an object, but that's just an implementation detail. It's completely hidden from the outside world. You could write a different version with the same API, but which did not create the private object, and your clients would be unable to tell the difference. You really are using the "class" as a namespace for some public functions that your clients can call.